# Is DLIB a good open source library for developing my own machine learning algorithms in C++?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, data-mining, dlib

Is DLIB a good open source library for developing my own machine learning algorithms in C++?

How about other ones, such as libSVM, SHOGUN?

Comment: All that really depends on what you are trying to do. And it seems that you are looking to use existing algorithms not invent your own which I do not recommend.

Comment: @Steve: Avoid the NIH syndrome :-)

Comment: I recommend starting with existing algorithms as a learning exercise and if they aren't good enough, inventing your own - "standing on the shoulders of giants..."

Comment: I agree with Andrew S. Maybe you should check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_%28software%29 That way you can compare performance of your algorithm against other ones that are implemented in Orange

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good source for information about machine learning open source software is [mloss.org](http://mloss.org/software/), where you can find 20 projects that use C++. Study the descriptions and tags to select one that fits your needs.